# Deploy Phoenix application via docker and error with db connection

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am very new to elixir and phoenix. I am doing a deploy my testing project from docker hub with my docker-compose.yml and i had some error as below after i run command

> sudo docker-compose up

but i am not pretty sure if it is really go wrong with my database connection.
Below is my docker-compose.yml that i cut one part with database connection. I have configured mysql to support remote login as well.

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  nginx-certs:
  nginx-dhparam:
  nginx-vhost:
  nginx-html:

services:
  app:
    image: mesasok/khana_repo:0.03
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      BROKER_BATCH_SIZE: '1000'
      DATABASE_HOST: '172.31.20.100'
      DATABASE_NAME: 'ask'
      DATABASE_PASS: '123456'
      DATABASE_USER: 'root'
      ...... more .......
```

[image: Error after deploy]

Comment: That is definitely a bug in mariaex, I would recommend you to file a report here: https://github.com/xerions/mariaex/blob/v0.8.3/lib/mariaex/protocol.ex

Comment: Although that is only being triggered because you are failing to connect to the server. The bug is not in connecting but in reporting that there was an error. Are you able to successfully connect to this DB from your machine without docker?

Comment: Yes i can connect to this DB from my machine without docker.

Comment: So my suggestion is to file a bug report and meanwhile you can fork the mariaex project and add a `IO.inspect(error)` right below this line: https://github.com/xerions/mariaex/blob/v0.8.3/lib/mariaex/protocol.ex#L1137. Then if you try again it should at least print the actual error, allowing you to move forward.

Comment: Oh, you can also try mariaex master, maybe the issue has been fixed there.